# Надо загрузить canvas со страницы на компьютер пользователя

Tags: html, canvas, download

Добрый день! Хочу дать возможность пользователю, сохранить у себя на компьютере скриншот, динамически сформированного элемента страницы. Со скриншотом проблем нет. А вот дальше знаний не хватает. Можете помочь?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", canvasDownload);

function canvasDownload(){
var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
}

function createRect(){
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle="blue";
context.fillRect(10, 8, 50, 67);
context.closePath();
}

createRect();
```

```css
#canvas{
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="btn" type="button">Скачать canvas</button>
```

Обещаю изучить методы загрузки, после того, как увижу, как это реализуется)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для универсальности лучше так. С хромом и файрфокс просто сохраняют, другие вроде как в отдельной вкладке открывают. Лучше варианта нет. (Конечно если вы не хотите отдавать картинку через сервер.)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn-download");

btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    btn.href = dataURL;
});

function createRect(){
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle="blue";
context.fillRect(10, 8, 50, 67);
context.closePath();
}

createRect();
```

```css
#canvas{
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<a href="#" class="button" id="btn-download" download="my-file-name.png">Download</a>
```