# Сгенирировать клик по сслыке

Tags: javascript, html, события

Добрый день! не думал, что возникнуть с этим проблемы, но увы). Суть проблемы в заголовке. Почему-то не получается.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", goToGoogle);

function goToGoogle(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  btn.removeEventListener("click", goToGoogle);
  var ev = new Event("click");
  btn.href = "http://google.com";
  btn.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="btn">Клик</a>
```

Здесь, правда, вообще, не переходит, но на локалке - 2-й клик срабатывает норм.Но надо-то, чтобы работало с первого раза)

Кстати, вопрос можно переформулировать: почему не срабатывает `dispathEvent` на ссылке, в которой `href` добавляется динамически? Потому что, если `href` есть изначально, то все нормально работает

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что означает имитация клика....

Comment: @Air, В вопросе слово 'иммитация' нигде не используется. Речь идет о генерации клика. Собственно и код о том же. Слово 'иммитация'  я использовал в комментариях к ответу. Согласен - оно не совсем подходит к описанной проблеме

Comment: Честно, не понимаю, что именно ты хочешь реализовать...

Comment: @Air, ну, я как обычно - для вопроса локализую проблему. А хочу реализовать - скачивание динамически сформированного контента. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803716/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-canvas-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Comment: @Air, глобально я проблему решил...решил не ждать клика, и генерирую скачиваемый контент  заранее. Но этот вопрос все равно остается - почему не работает `dispatchEvent` на ссылке, в которой `href` добавляется динамически.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо btn.href нужно window.location.href = 'http://google.com' либо window.replace('http://google.com')

Comment: Так это не будет иммитация клика по ссылке